# How do i make my javascript code run every Sunday at 23:59 pm in my backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

So I am making an app about weekly statistics and in my backend I want to make it reset all of my stats at Sunday 23:59 pm each week.  How should i go about this so it does not disturb the rest of my backend, it is written in javascript and node (express)?

Comment: You would need to implement a cron library of some kind. i.e [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

Comment: Have a look at cronjobs

Comment: Thanks :) Il'l look into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`node-cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) library allows you to achieve this pretty easily:

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
const resetStats = () => { console.log("Resetting stats ...") };

// 59 23 * * SUN === every sunday at 23:59
cron.schedule('59 23 * * SUN', resetStats())
```

Comment: If you don't mind why cron job, why we should not / can not  use simple node js.

Comment: Welll, you can certainly implement it yourself - in cases like this I try not to reinvent the wheel though. Especially since such an implementation is not that trivial in my opinion:) If you're interested how it could be done, you can just take a look at the source: https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron/tree/master/src

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using a cron job. I will send you a link to an article hopefully that will help you complete your application.[node cron jobs by example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples)

#cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) package in Node to do it.

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('0 59 23 * * 0', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every Sunday at 23:59');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
job.start();
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't it be  `59 23 * * 0`?